# How to return an array of C# strings (string[]) to unmanaged C++ code?

Tags: c#, .net, com, interop

How to return an array of C# strings (string[]) to unmanaged C++ code, and then use it from C++?

```
// Is it correct ???
[ComVisible(true)]
public string[] Foo()
{
    return new string[] {"A", "B", "C"};    
}
```

C++ code ??

Comment: Use the COM/OLE Viewer to look at the typelibrary you get when you register for COM. This allows you to see the IDL from which you can see what type is generated.

Answer (score 0):

You should define an interface to be used from the unmanaged C++ code, either as a DLL export interface, or as a COM interface.
This way you can control how the strings are marshaled.
([See MSDN Article on Default Marshaling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719895.aspx))

An other way is to use C++/CLI in between, and pass your strings that way.
([See C++/CLI on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xey702bw.aspx))